# Cheetah template engine calling python base function

Tags: python, cherrypy, cheetah

I am using Cheetah template together with Cherrypy, below is my main python file

```
Main.py:
def multiple(a,b):
    return a*b

def index(self):
    t = Template('template.tmpl')
    #blah implementation here
```

In my template file, I wish to achieve

```
<body>
    <div>
       $multiple(2,3)
    </div>
</body>
```

Anyone has an idea how can I get this implement? Many thanks.

Regards,
Andy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
t = Template("template.tmpl")
t.multiple = multiple
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Yup, this one works. I tried before but I didn't declare it in the global scope or using the self.multiple.

Answer (score 2):

try with the searchList argument :

```
def index(self):
    t = Template('template.tmpl', searchList=[multiple])
```

It allows you to define "placeholders" that you will be able to use in template definition.

Answer (score 1):

This may answer it:

```
import Cheetah
import Cheetah.Template


def multiple(a,b):
    return a*b

print Cheetah.Template.Template(file='template.tmpl',
                                searchList=[dict(multiple=multiple)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just import Main in the template?

```
#from Main import multiple
<body>
    <div>
       $multiple(2,3)
    </div>
</body>
```